# Ios: how to avoid video orientation change during capture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, ios-camera

I have an iOS app that only supports portrait. When rotating the device the video captured by the RTCCameraVideoCapturer (WebRTC) rotates to landscape orientation, even when the rest of the UI stays in portrait. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to RTCCameraVideoCapturer codebases ? Also, I am not sure which version of the WebRTC codebases you are working with. And, in your application ; is `landscape` mode is the only mode that you are intending to support ?

There should be rotation calculation method that listen to rotation changes. You can just disabled it, or can use your preferred fixed set of rotation in spite of default.

For example, taking from [this sample codebase](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-mirror/blob/master/webrtc/sdk/objc/Framework/Classes/PeerConnection/RTCCameraVideoCapturer.m#L198) ; you can just only use `RTCVideoRotation_90` to have landscape orientation only.